# Sequelize join on where condition returned from first table or return object values in an array derrived from foreach coming up empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach, sequelize.js

I've been trying to figure out this for a while now so any help would be very much appreciated.

I have one table called Interaction that searches with the client user's id and returns all interactions where they are the target user. Then I want to return the names of those users who initiated the interaction through the User table.

I tried using include to join the User table but I can't get the user's names using the where clause because it is based on a value returned in the first search of the Interaction table and don't know if I can search on a value that isn't the primary key or how?

The closest I've gotten is to use foreach and add the users to an array but I can't get the array to return in my response, because outside of the loop it is empty. I've tried suggestions I've found but can't figure out how to return the array outside of the foreach, if this is the best option. I am sure it is something really stupid on my behalf. TIA.

This is my attempt at include function:

```
getInvited: (req, res, next) => {
    var user = {}
    user = req.user;
    let usrId = user[0]['facebookUserId'];
    var userObjArray = [];
    Interaction.findAll({
        where: {
            targetUserId: usrId,
            status: 'invited',
        },
        include: [{
            model: User,
            attributes: [
                'firstName'
            ],
            where: {
                facebookUserId: IwantToJoinOnInteraction.userId // replace with working code?
        }]
    }).then(function (users) {
        res.send(users);
    }).catch(next);
}
```

Or my attempt at foreach:

```
getInvited: (req, res, next) => {
    var user = {}
    user = req.user;
    let usrId = user[0]['facebookUserId'];
    var userObjArray = [];
    Interaction.findAll({
        where: {
            targetUserId: usrId,
            status: 'invited',
        }
     }).then(function (interactions) {
         interactions.forEach((interaction) => {
             User.findOne({
                 where: {
                     facebookUserId: interaction.userId // this is the where clause I don't know how to add in my first attempt with include
                 },
                 attributes: ['firstName', 'facebookUserId']          
             }).then(function (user) { 
                 userObjArray.push(user['dataValues']);
                 console.log(userObjArray); // on the last loop it contains everything I need
             })
         })
         res.status(200).send(userObjArray); // empty
    }).catch(next);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for all promises before sending the response. Your code runs async. With the `forEach` you are calling `User.findOne` async but you don't wait for all `User.findOne` to finish. A convenient way to make this work is [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). You can pass an array of promises and the returned promise resolves to an array of all the resolved promises.

```
Promise.all(interactions.map(interaction => User.findOne(...)))
  .then(users => {
    res.status(200).send(users.map(user => user.dataValues))
  })
```

You could write this much more easy to read woth async/await

```
getInvited: async (req, res, next) => {
  ...
  const interactions = await Interaction.findAll(...)
  const users = await Promise.all(interactions.map(interaction => User.findOne(...)))
  res.status(200).send(users.map(user => user.dataValues))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is now working. I wish you many good things for your help :)